# Substring the following strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add a code that substrings the below strings?
I need the `questionID` from the `variableID`, that is, anything between the two underscores (_). 
Examples:

- `hcm_q10_568`
- `py_q10x_45`
- `sub_q1_34`
- `la_q8a_67`

I have this code that works for specific style string but doesn't satisfy all:

```
(substring(@s,charindex('q'',@s),charindex('_',reverse(@s))))
```

Could you give me some ideas? How to get this working for all the strings.

Comment: Look at the optional 3rd parameter in CHARINDEX and see if that doesn't give you an idea:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `parsename()` (if there are no periods in the strings):

```
select 
    middle = parsename(replace(str,'_','.'),2)
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LWNP30293

returns:

```
+--------+
| middle |
+--------+
| q10    |
| q10x   |
| q1     |
| q8a    |
+--------+
```

---

For strings with periods, you can use a temporary replacement character and swap it out and back in again:

```
select 
    middle = replace(parsename(replace(replace(str,'.',char(29)),'_','.'),2),char(29),'.')
from t
```

Reference:

- [Using the PARSENAME function to split delimited data - Damian Maclennen - 2003-11-10](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data)

---

If you really want to use `substring()` and `charindex()` you can like so:

```
select 
     middle=substring(str
      ,(charindex('_',str)+1)
      ,(charindex('_',str,(charindex('_',str)+1))-charindex('_',str)-1)
    )
from t
```

Comment: I'll give you an UV if you give a non-2012 version ;)

Comment: @scsimon `parsename()` isn't 2012+. That's just bad documentation on microsoft's website.

Comment: Why do you think this wouldn't work pre-2012?   I love PARSENAME hacks!   +1 from me.

Comment: But btw, this solution wouldn't work if there were any naturally occurring periods in the strings.   Since there are none in the examples, you are assuming there are none in the actual data.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm I have never heard of parsename before this is something new I learnt. Thank you again

Comment: ha, i literally avoided it in previous versions based off that. Shenanigans!

Comment: This will fail if the string contains period characters.

Comment: But if there ARE period characters, they can be handled with two more nested REPLACES, so PARSENAME FTW!

Comment: @TabAlleman Xavier J My variable IDs do not contain any periods thats why this is just perfect for me to breakdown the string.

Comment: @vap0991 don't be so selfish!   We are making this answer more valuable to future readers.   : )

Comment: @TabAlleman But I wasn't even being selfish also if I knew i had a period in my variableid i would have raised it. I am still new here so little niceness won't hurt !

Comment: @XavierJ I don't think your solution is any better. For example if the string has more than 2 `_`. E.g. `S_TX_q12_234` your solution will give `TX` right? I know that this is not what the original question assumes, but for a full general solution one might want to take care of that as well.

Comment: @vap0991 don't worry, I was only teasing.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHARINDEX.  Terse, but foolproof.

```
declare @input varchar(50)
declare @index1 int, @index2 int
declare @result varchar(50)
select @input = 'my_string_here';
select @index1=CHARINDEX('_', @input, 1)
if (@index1 > 0)
begin
   select @index2 = CHARINDEX('_', @input, @index1+1)
   if (@index2 > 0)
        select @result = SUBSTRING(@input, @index1+1, @index2-@index1-1)
end
print @result
```